# get img path on clisk with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am currently trying to get the path of an image when clicking on it using jquery. The images is printed out in a loop using php. Is there a command in jquery to fetch the img src?

here is my jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(\"#gallerythumbnail\").click(function( event ) {
        alert(\"The img source/path???\");
    });
});
</script>
```

and the img tag:

```
<img src='".$picsarray[$picsfrom]."' id='gallerythumbnail'>
```

does someone know how to do this? 
any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `alert(this.src)` <- but that won't work with multiple images with the same ID, as ID's are unique.

Comment: yeah you are right about that, it will only work with the first image in my array. any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the image id to class, as all id's should be unique. 
so change your images like this

```
<img src='".$picsarray[$picsfrom]."' class='gallerythumbnail'>
```

and do this in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".gallerythumbnail").click(function( event ) {
    alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it is only working with my first image in the loop. Do you have a solution for this?